# Unusual StackOverflowException in ListDictionaryInternal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have class library with a bunch of static methods. While trying to call one of them, I experience unhandled StackOverflowException somewhere in the ListDictionaryInternal class.

I tried enabling .Net Framework (v 4.5.2) stepping, surrounding call with try/catch block, and executing it step by step. **When I place continue statement after Appendix A comment, then comment it while debugging, method works as expected.** Otherwise I cannot even hit breakpoint at the start at the method. I also tried to call method with all parameters set to null, but it did not help either.

```
public static List<CalcSector> Split(List<CalcSector> calibration, List<ProfilePoint> profile, List<MeasurementPoint> additionalPoints)
{
    double lengthCorridor = 10d;
    double lengthEpsilon = 1d;
    if (!(calibration?.Any() ?? false)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(calibration), "Empty calibration table");
    if (!(profile?.Any() ?? false)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(profile), "Empty profile points collection");
    for (int i = 0; i < calibration.Count - 1; i++)
        if (Math.Abs(calibration[i].EndDistance - calibration[i + 1].StartDistance) > lengthEpsilon)
            throw new ArgumentException($"calibration[{i}]", "Calibration table integrity is compromised");
    List<CalcSector> result = new List<CalcSector>();
    List<ProfilePoint> SummitPoints = new List<ProfilePoint>();
    calibration.ForEach(x => result.Add(x));
    profiles = profile.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).ToList();
    //
    if (additionalPoints?.Any() ?? false)
        foreach (MeasurementPoint mp in additionalPoints.Where(x => x.Id != int.MinValue && x.Id != int.MaxValue))
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                if (Math.Abs(mp.Distance - result[i].StartDistance) > lengthEpsilon && Math.Abs(mp.Distance - result[i].EndDistance) > lengthEpsilon && mp.Distance > result[i].StartDistance && mp.Distance < result[i].EndDistance)
                {
                    CalcSector c = new CalcSector()
                    {
                        StartDistance = mp.Distance,
                        StartHeight = BinaryHeightSearch(mp.Distance),
                        StartPointId = mp.Id,
                        EndDistance = result[i].EndDistance,
                        EndHeight = result[i].EndHeight,
                        Length = result[i].EndDistance - mp.Distance,
                        Thickness = result[i].Thickness,
                    };
                    result[i].EndDistance = mp.Distance;
                    result[i].EndHeight = c.StartHeight;
                    result[i].EndPointId = mp.Id;
                    c.Volume = result[i].Volume / result[i].Length * c.Length;
                    result[i].Length -= c.Length;
                    result[i].Volume -= c.Volume;
                    result.Insert(i + 1, c);
                    break;
                }
                else if (Math.Abs(mp.Distance - result[i].StartDistance) < lengthEpsilon)
                    result[i].StartPointId = mp.Id;
                else if (Math.Abs(mp.Distance - result[i].EndDistance) < lengthEpsilon)
                    result[i].EndPointId = mp.Id;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    bool hasSpikes = true;
    while (hasSpikes)
    {
        hasSpikes = false;
        //Appendix A
        for (int j = 0; j < result.Count; j++)
        {
            result[j].z = -1d * (result[j].StartHeight - result[j].EndHeight) / (result[j].EndDistance - result[j].StartDistance);
            result[j].sI = start = BinaryProfileSearch(result[j].StartDistance);
            result[j].eI = end = BinaryProfileSearch(result[j].EndDistance);
            for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
                if (Math.Abs(result[j].z * (profiles[i].Distance - result[j].StartDistance) + result[j].StartHeight - profiles[i].Height) > lengthCorridor)
                {
                    int maxIndex = -1;
                    double maxH = double.MinValue;
                    int minIndex = -1;
                    double minH = double.MaxValue;
                    for (; start < end; start++)
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(result[j].z * (profiles[start].Distance - result[j].StartDistance) + result[j].StartHeight - profiles[start].Height) <= lengthCorridor)
                            continue;
                        if (result[j].z * (profiles[i].Distance - result[j].StartDistance) + result[j].StartHeight - profiles[i].Height > maxH)
                        {
                            maxH = profiles[start].Height;
                            maxIndex = start;
                        }
                        if (result[j].z * (profiles[i].Distance - result[j].StartDistance) + result[j].StartHeight - profiles[i].Height < minH)
                        {
                            minH = profiles[start].Height;
                            minIndex = start;
                        }
                    }
                    int target = Math.Min(maxIndex, minIndex);
                    CalcSector c = new CalcSector()
                    {
                        StartDistance = profiles[target].Distance,
                        StartHeight = profiles[target].Height,
                        sI = target,
                        EndDistance = result[j].EndDistance,
                        EndHeight = result[j].EndHeight,
                        EndPointId = result[j].EndPointId,
                        eI = result[j].eI,
                        Length = result[j].EndDistance - profiles[target].Distance,
                        Thickness = result[j].Thickness,
                    };
                    result[j].EndDistance = c.StartDistance;
                    result[j].EndHeight = c.StartHeight;
                    result[j].EndPointId = null;
                    result[j].eI = target;
                    result[j].z = -1d * (result[j].StartHeight - result[j].EndHeight) / (result[j].EndDistance - result[j].StartDistance);
                    c.Volume = result[j].Volume / result[j].Length * c.Length;
                    result[j].Length -= c.Length;
                    result[j].Volume -= c.Volume;
                    result.Insert(j + 1, c);
                    hasSpikes = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < result.Count; j++)
    {
        result[j].Diameter = 1000d * Math.Sqrt(4d * result[j].Volume / Constants["PI"] / result[j].Length);
        result[j].OrdNum = j;
    }
    result.First().StartPointId = int.MinValue;
    result.Last().EndPointId = int.MaxValue;

    for (int i = 1; i < profiles.Count - 1; i++)
        if (profiles[i - 1].Height < profiles[i].Height && profiles[i].Height > profiles[i + 1].Height)
            SummitPoints.Add(profiles[i]);
    return result;
}
```

```
public class CalcSector
{
    public int OrdNum;
    public double StartDistance;
    public double StartHeight;
    public int? StartPointId;
    public double EndDistance;
    public double EndHeight;
    public int? EndPointId;
    public double Length;
    public double Volume;
    public double Diameter;
    public double Thickness;
    public int sI;
    public int eI;
    public double z;
}
public class ProfilePoint
{
    public double Distance;
    public double Height;
}
public class MeasurementPoint
{
    public int Id;
    public double Distance;
}
```

I expect this method to split some of the original CalcSectors into smaller ones, but all I have is this unhandled fatal exception.

Added:

```
private static int BinaryProfileSearch(double distance)
{
    if (profiles == null || profiles.Count == 0)
        return -1;
    //assuming that profile points are already ordered by distance
    if (distance <= profiles.First().Distance)
        return 0;
    if (distance >= profiles.Last().Distance)
        return profiles.Count - 1;
    int first = 0;
    int last = profiles.Count - 1;
    while (first + 1 < last)
    {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if (distance <= profiles[mid].Distance)
            last = mid;
        else
            first = mid + 1;
    }
    if (distance - profiles[first].Distance > profiles[last].Distance - distance)
        return last;
    else
        return first;
}
```

Comment: You probably calling a method recursively and getting stuck in an endless loop.  I would create a output text file and write debug data to file to help debug the loop.  Make sure after each write you do a flush() to put all info into the file.  You should find the loop very quickly.

Comment: A method this long is bound to generate a lot of errors. Try rewriting the whole method by using multiple methods. That should improve readability and also make it easier to debug. As a general guideline, never use a for-loop inside another for-loop but put that for-loop in a separate method with whatever data it needs to run.

Comment: First, I want to point out an error that we can't set two return result code in the return method. Because return result represents that the method has ended. The correct method to solve this is that add {} after if sentence.                         Second, could you tell me what is your expected result and please provide the related code about BinaryHeightSearch?

Answer (score 0):

The solution came quite unexpected: invalid value of 8087 control word. Next line changes it back.

```
_controlfp(0x9001F, 0xFFFFF);
```